# In a batch file I want to Compare a Variable(which is a string) to a set pattern and return a number value

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am kind of new to programming and I decided to try and make an interactive form for creating a flat file database for my sql class in school that could be loaded into sql server via set tasks.

I have a .txt file that is a flat file for a database

example of flat file, each colomn is separated by ; and the eol is :

```
ID;FName;LName;FavColor;Gender: 
1;Scott;Muhlestein;Silver;Male:
```

I have imported the contents of the file to memory and each line is a different %var#% and I want to compare the %var1% (being the Headers of the database) with a pattern as shown below:

A#C = Any # of Characters

```
if %var1%==(A#C);(A#C);(A#C);(A#C): set colnum=4
if %var1%==(A#C);(A#C);(A#C): set colnum=3
if %var1%==(A#C);(A#C): set colnum=2
```

max colnum=10, Currently

The pattern is any number of characters separated by a semicolon and ending with a colon

Once I have this new variable(colnum) I can restrict the number of entries to the correct amount when the user tries to add a new record.

Any Ideas or is their a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of tokens in a delimited string, you can convert the tokens to spaces and run the string through a basic for loop (use quotation marks to preserve existing spaces so your count doesn't get thrown off).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (data.txt) do (
    set line=%%A
    set line=!line:?= !

    set counter=0
    for %%B in (!line!) do set /a counter+=1
    echo There are !counter! columns in %%A.
)
pause
```

Where data.txt is the text file that contains your data. The one I used for testing looked like this:

> ID;FName;LName;FavColor;Gender:
>   1;Scott;Muhlestein;Silver;Male:
>   2;Jane;"Is Awesome";Brown;Female:

All three of these lines return a value of 5 columns

Comment: I think the line `set line=!line:;= !` is not necessary since `;` is a delimiter for plain `for` anyway, so you could get rid of the variable `line`; moreover I'm afraid this will fail if any of the lines contain `*` and/or `?`...

Comment: @aschipfl - didn't know about semicolons being natural delimiters; thanks. The code should now be able to handle question marks, although I'm still looking for a way to do substring substitution with asterisks.

Comment: Besides the _SPACE_, the characters _TAB_ `,` `;` `=` act as native delimiters in plain `for`, as command line argument separators, in fact generally in `cmd` (with some exceptions, of course, like `if` for instance, which treats the `=` particularly)... awaiting your substring substritution approach impatiently...

Comment: Doesn't work with empty columns either eg `1;Scott;Muhlestein;;Male:`

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Import first line into "var1" variable (you did this already)
set /P "var1=" < test.txt

rem Count the number of fields separated by ; (or space, comma or equal-sign)
set colnum=0
for %%a in (%var1%) do set /A colnum+=1

echo colnum = %colnum%
```

If the headers may include spaces (or comma or equal-sign), the simple additional trick below is needed:

```
for %%a in ("%var1:;=" "%") do set /A colnum+=1
```

**EDIT**: *New method added*

Previous trick will fail if any header include wild-card characters: `*?`. The solution below allows special characters and wild-cards in the headers:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Import first line into "var1" variable (you did this already)
set /P "var1=" < test.txt

rem Set maximum number of columns
set maxColnum=10

rem Count the number of fields separated by semicolon;
rem the fields may include other separators and wild-cards
set "str=%var1%;"
set colnum=0
for /L %%i in (1,1,%maxColnum%) do if defined str (
   set /A colnum+=1
   set "str=!str:*;=!"
)
echo colnum = %colnum%
```

Comment: +1 for this elegant solution and the intelligent trick; however, I'm afraid this will fail if any of the lines contain `*` and/or `?`, and the trick doesn't accept `"`...

Comment: @aschipfl: I added a new method that works with any delimiter or wild-card character: `,;=*?`

Comment: Wait `?` is a wildcard character? How did i not know this?!? Off to SS64 to research...

Comment: @Arescet: Wild-cards are described in several DOS/Windows documentation. For example, in [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690414(v=vs.85).aspx) you may read: "The asterisk (*) and question mark (?) are used as wildcard characters, as they are in MS-DOS and Windows. The asterisk matches any sequence of characters, whereas the question mark matches any single character".

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (
"(A#C);(A#C);(A#C);(A#C):"
"(A#C);(A#C);(A#C):"
"(A#C);(A#C):" 
"(A#C);;(A#C):" 
"(A#C);(A#C);(A#C);(A#C) note no terminal-colon"
) DO SET "var=%%~a"&CALL :countcols

GOTO :EOF

:countcols
SET "workvar="
SET /a count=0
IF "%var:~-1%"==":" (
 SET "workvar=%var%"
 SET /a count=1
)
:countloop
IF DEFINED workvar (
 IF "%workvar:~0,1%"==";" SET /a count+=1
 SET "workvar=%workvar:~1%"
 GOTO countloop
)
ECHO "%var%" contains %count% columns

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a small demonstration.

The first part simply sets `var` to one of the strings (the `~` removes the enclosing quotes) and executes the `countcols` subroutine.

`countcols` first ensures `workvar` is "set" to *nothing* and `count` set to `0`.

Then, if the last character of `var` is a colon, sets `workvar` to the value of `var` and `count` to 1.

Then if `workvar` is defined, it checks the first character and counts 1 if it is a semicolon. It then removes the first character regardless.

This is repeated until `workvar` is *nothing* (and hence undefined).

Then as a demonstration, a report is created.

For more info about batch substrings, see

```
set /?
```

from the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to a count-check, you can even do a syntax-check with `findstr`:

```
echo %var#%|findstr /i "[0-9]*;[a-z]*;[a-z]*;[a-z]*:$" >nul &&echo correct||echo sorry, wrong Input
```

This checks, if there is a number, followed by a semicolon, followed by a string of letters, followed by a semicolon, followed by a string of letters, followed by a semicolon, followed by a string of letters, followed by a colon, followed by "end of string"

To be slightly adapted to work for names like "Müller" (other than the 26 Alphabet letters) or "Brown-Smith" (dash) or "Mc Scott" (space)

SomethingDark might be right and I misunderstood the question.

If you only need the number of columns:

```
set "colnum="
for %%i in (%var#%) do set /a colnum +=1
echo number of entries: %colnum% 
if "%var#:~-1%" neq ":" echo you forgot the colon
```

Comment: I may be misreading the question, but I was under the impression that he was asking if there is a way to count the number of occurrences of a substring (in this case, `;`) in a string.